# Why doesn't the Kivy ActionBar Work Properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, kivy

I was trying to create an actionbar using ideas for kivy pingball and action bar examples.
This is my Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Builder.load_string("""
<TitleBar>:
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Action Bar'
                with_previous: False
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                icon: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'
            ActionButton:
                important: True
                text: 'Important'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn2'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn3'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn4'
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'Group1'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn5'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn6'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn7'
""")
class TitleBar(Widget):
    pass
class TrialApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.size=(875,575)
        Window.borderless=True
        return TitleBar()

TrialApp().run()
```

Why is the ActionBar going to the bottom inspite the usage of `pos_hint: {'top':1}`?
Python 3.7.5 Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root `Widget` of your `App` is a simple `Widget`, which is not intened to be used as a container, and has no support for things like `pos_hint`. Try changing:

```
class TitleBar(Widget):
```

to

```
class TitleBar(FloatLayout):
```

This makes your root `Widget` a `FloatLayout`, which will handle `pos_hint`.

Comment: Thank you bt I found that 30seconds ago :) and posted the answer.

Comment: How do you make the action button do an action?

Comment: The `ActionButton` is just an extension of `Button`, so you can specify 'on_press' or `on_release` just like a regular `Button`.

Comment: doesnt it have 'on_moveover' or 'on_hover' or something?

Comment: I don't think it does. KivyMD has a `HoverBehavior` that you might be able to use.  You could probably come up with your own hover using something like `Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_motion)` and using `collide_point()` to check if the mouse position is over a `Widget` of interest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993245/position-of-the-kivy-label

Answer (score 0):

When you read the docs of [kivy.uix.actionbar](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.actionbar.html) , you get that instead of `Widget`, you need to use `FloatLayout`.
So the code must be:

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
class TitleBar(FloatLayout):
    pass
```