# Position of The Kivy Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

In the [same experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990739/how-to-assign-the-kivy-input-text-to-a-variable-immediately-on-pressing-enter), I tried to positionize a Label using this code:

```
class TetraApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.size=(875,600)
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        b = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')

#Here, the pos and pos hint doesnt seem to work for small values

        self.lab=Label(text="How Can I Help\n          You?", font_size='35',color =[0, 0, 0, 1],font_name='VarelaRound-Regular',pos=[0.1,0.01],pos_hint={'x': 0.005, 'y': 0})

        self.t = TextInput(hint_text='Say Something...', size_hint=(1,0.25), multiline=False)
        self.t.bind(on_text_validate=self.enterClicked)
        b.add_widget(TitleBar())
        b.add_widget(self.lab)
        b.add_widget(self.t)
        Window.borderless=True
        return b
```

This is what i get:
[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not positioning (the `BoxLyout` handles that), but the `size` of your `Label`. You need to provide a `height` for the `Label`. Something like:

```
self.lab=Label(text="How Can I Help\n          You?", font_size='35',color =[0, 0, 0, 1], font_name='VarelaRound-Regular', size_hint_y=None, height=100)
```

Your `TitleBar` has a fixed height, the `TextInput` is set to take up a quarter of the `BoxLayout` height, and since the default `size_hint_y` is 1.0, your `Label` takes the rest of the space. Giving the `Label` a fixed height, leaves the rest of the space to the `TextInput`. You could use `size_hint_y` instead of the fixed height, and that would allow the `Label` and the `TextInput` to share the space proportional to their `size_hint_y` values.

Comment: the textinput dissappered

Comment: I tried `self.lab=Label(text="How Can I Help\nYou?", font_size='35',color =[0, 0, 0, 1],font_name='VarelaRound-Regular', size_hint=(None,None), size=(100,500),halign='center',pos_hint={'x': 0.45, 'y': 0},pos=(0,0))`

Comment: what if i use floatlayout?

Comment: You should consult the [BoxLayout documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html). Especially the section describing `size_hint`.